# How to create a Class when its attributes are dynamic & variable in Java, C++ or any Object-Oriented Language?

Tags: java, c++, vb.net, oop

Ok, in Object-Oriented Language (OOL), when creating a Class we often know in advance all its attributes. Ex, Item class should have a fixed attributes (Color, model, brand, price). So we just:

```
   public Class Item{
     private String color;
     private String model;
     //etc more attribute here

     //& set & get method for all attributes
     public String getColor() {
         return color;
     }

     public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
     }

     public String getModel() {
         return model;
     }

     public void setModel(String model) {
         this.model = model;
     }
    }
```

But what if all the attributes are dynamic? Ex, in 1 company, their item attributes could be color, brand, but in other company, they don't have color & brand attributes but have width, height, size...

How to create a Class that accepts dynamic attributes in Java, C++ or in any OOL?

Comment: In programming, we often know in advance the variables we need (`int x; char * str;`). But what if all the variables are dynamic? Ex, we could be reading lines of data from the network; some users might enter 20 lines, but others only 5... How to create a program that accepts variable amounts of data?

Comment: There are a lot of different options, but which is correct for your situation depends on the details. Can you elaborate? How much do these attributes vary? Are there a small number of different possible attributes or attribute sets? How are you consuming these objects? What needs to be consistent in these objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to create a Class that accepts dynamic attributes in Java, C++ or in any OOL?

It really depends on how you want to use this.  In many cases, you could rework your class to contain some type of dynamically growing collection, such as a [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) in C++ or a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (or [`Dictionary`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html)) in Java.

This allows you to create and add arbitrary data per instance with a key chosen at runtime.

Comment: Dictionary is obsolete. Use Map instead.

Comment: @EricStein Edited to include Map

Comment: sound complicated, is this the most elegant solution? any better solution?

Comment: @MinhHai This tends to be, by its nature, complicated, as you're trying to fit a dynamic view of the world into a statically compiled mental model.  Some languages (ie: C#) have features (the `dynamic` keyword) to simplify this somewhat, but it's always a bit odd when working in a statically typed OO language to create types that are truly "dynamic".

Comment: Thax Reed for ur answer, maybe someone who is genuine can develop a new kind of language

Comment: @MinhHai Look at dynamic languages - javascript, python, etc, all support this type of "extensibility" at runtime without issue.

Answer (score 0):

**.NET**

I would first start by analysing your requirement, this isn't something that you will see often. Maybe your classes aren't set up properly.

An option could be to store in a Dictionary

With new version of .NET they have the [dynamic keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx) that can help create dynamic properties like the ViewBag.

You can also use reflection with [Reflection Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1zby21a.aspx) or the [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that this is a prime example of when you should use *inheritance*.  Take the following for example:

```
Abstract Class Item
{
    // This class will never be instantiated, but it can hold 
    // things that are common to all Items, such as sale price.

    private int price;

    public int getPrice() { return price; }

    // etc.
}

Class VendorOneItem : Item
{
    // This class gets 'price' and 'getPrice' by default, 
    // since it inherits from Item
    private String color;
    private String model;
    // etc.
}

Class VendorTwoItem : Item
{
    // This class also gets 'price' and 'getPrice'
    private Double width;
    private Double height;
    // etc.
}
```

I know this doesn't take the route of dynamically reading in the data, but this is the more clear-cut way in my mind.  Even if you are somehow able to read in all of the data dynamically, how would be able to process that data?  As Reed noted, you could have a Dictionary or a Map of some sort, which is reasonable.  You'd have data that might look like:

```
{"key": value}
{"Color": "blue"}
{"Price": 9.99}
{"Model": 1234-567-890}
```

or

```
{"Price": 129.99}
{"Height": 12.750}
{"Width": 8.55}
```

But then you're just shifting your problem from figuring out the attributes at compile time to figuring out the attributes at run-time.  In order to process these two, some part of your code will have to know what to do with `"Width"` and `"Height"`, and it will also need to know what to do with `"Model"` and `"Color"`.  Reflection is one possibility, but what's being described by these items are fundamentally different, and it might be next to impossible to generalize an algorithm that deals with their details.

It seems far easier to me to start with a base class and have inherited classes that know the details.  You can even make collections of `Item` in your code along the way, without having to know the exact type of each object.

In C++:

```
std::vector<*Item> items;
items.push_back(new VendorOneItem());
items.push_back(new VendorTwoItem());
```

Now say you add this to the `Item` class:

```
virtual public void ProcessItem()=0; //This will throw compilation errors
// if all derived classes don't define ProcessItem
```

So now, back where the vector `items` is defined, you can do this:

```
items[0].ProcessItem();
items[1].ProcessItem();
```

And it makes no difference that the two objects are instantiations of different classes.  They both *must* implement ProcessItem, so there's no problem figuring out which functions to call.